# Downloading storage file using vue3 and Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, vuejs3

My file is stored in `storage folder`, when i click on download button to `download image file`, `un willingly .txt file is downloading` containing response data.

How can i make this code work to download image from storage folder.

**SQL column data:**

```
file.jpg in file_name column
123 in custom_code column
```

**Controller:**

```
public function getdata(Request $request)
    {
        $files = Files::where('custom_code','=',$request->id)->first();
      
        $image_name= Files::where('custom_code','=',$request->id)->pluck('file_name');
        
        $image = Storage::download('uploads',$image_name);
        
        return response()->json([
            'files'=> $files, 
           'image'=> $image,     
          ], 200);
          
    }
```

**VUE:**

```
function download(){
 axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-data/"+state.input_code, {responseType: 'blob'})
                .then(response => {
                   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
                  const link = document.createElement('a');
                  link.href = url;
                  link.setAttribute('download', response.data.file_name);
                  document.body.appendChild(link);
                  link.click();
                })
                .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
                });
            }
```

**HTML:**

```
<button @click="download()">Download</button>
```

why it's downloading text file which includes response data instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning data from the server as JSON:

```php
return response()->json([
    'files'=> $files, 
    'image'=> $image,     
], 200);
```

[JSON is a text format](http://www.json.org/json-en.html). This is why your front-end is receiving text.

Your front-end code creates a link to a local copy of the JSON its just received, then creates an anchor tag, points the anchor tag at this link and programmatically clicks it (all redundant steps):

```js
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data])); // Create link to local copy of JSON
const link = document.createElement('a'); // Create anchor tag
link.href = url; // set href of anchor tag to link created to local copy of JSON
link.setAttribute('download', response.data.file_name); // Set redundant attribute - never used
document.body.appendChild(link); // Append anchor tag to body
link.click(); // Programmatically click link
```

You should use `return Storage::download('uploads',$image_name);` instead.

Comment: what should i change to download only file.

Comment: `return Storage::download('uploads',$image_name);`

Comment: how should i declare it in vue without response, can you please edit your answer so i can mark as solved. Thanks